# Manage state of gui

Tags: c++, events, state

I'm working on a graphical program that let's you connect or host a server. It has a field to enter the IP. Now there're 2 states: `Hosting` & `Connecting`. When hosting the IP field should be disabled. To do so I would add the following to the `HostConnectChanged` event:

```
if(state == Hosting)
{
    ipField.enable(false);
}
else if(state == Connecting)
{
    ipField.enable(true);
}
```

In my opinion this is a resonable way to handle gui state in a simple manner. The problem is adding another type of state to the program. It can be connected/hosting or disconnected. When it's connected the IP field should be disabled, too.

```
if(state == Hosting)
{
    ipField.enable(false);
}
else if(state == Connecting)
{
    if(state2 == Idle)
        ipField.enable(true);
}
if(state2 == Running)
{
    ipField.enable(false);
}
else if(state2 == Idle)
{
    if(state == Connecting)
        ipField.enable(true);
}
```

I think you see where this is going. How do larger programs deal with multiple states? Shouldn't this be a well known problem in gui programming with an easy solution?

Answer (score 0):

Larger programs always make heavy use of [separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/), and keep states at local as possible to relevant objects.  One very common for handling such state dependent behavior is the [state design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state).

**If your two states are independent:**

Ideally several different classes of object would use each their own state machine.  For example some controls on a form may depend on the connection state.  Some other controls could depend on the modification state in the form.  The global state of the component (e.g. the form) then simply emerge from the combination of the states of its parts (e.g. connected/modified, or connected/unchanged).

**If your sates are dependent:**

In your case however, the two states are dependent, because `Running` and `Connecting` seem incompatible.  The easiest way would certainly to work with a compound state machine, where the valid states are all the allowed combinations. Then use the state pattern with the compound states.